# How to cure SMPS output to get upset by a switching device

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have been having ringing spike issues at the output of SMPS power supplies. I don't know what is this phenomenon is about but it is definitely related to switching devices on the same electrical network. When a switch or switching device is on the same electrical network. The switching device upsets the SMPS output. This is directly related to my previous [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405508/what-could-be-causing-this-problem). Bu that time I didn't figure out the issue starts with SMPS output getting upset.

To demonstrate that I used a grinder as shown below:

[image]

And next to the grinder from the same power strip a 5V SMPS is powered.

Here is the output of the 5V power supply and the spikes "during" the short time the grinder is swithcing ON:

[image]

And here looks like high frequency ringing when AC coupled:

[image]

The problem is this power supply noise propagates through all sensitive devices it powers.

Does anybody have experience with such phenomenon? I even tried with EMI power line filter and isolation transformer but it didn't help. I guess SMPS already have filters at their input. Is there a way to filter out this at the power supply output? Would that issue happen with a linear supply?

Comment: How long is the ground clip lead on your oscilloscopes probe?

Comment: are you sure this is real? as @Marla is alluding to

Comment: @Marla 15 cm. But I don't think this is a measurement error due to the wrong probing. I'm saying that because when there is no scope this SMPS upsets the sensitive devices it powers. There is a direct relation between the switching device upsetting the SMPS output. Scope measurement came later after the issue.

Comment: Does  interference (not waveform) continue when grinder continues to run, or only interference when grinder is initiated?

Comment: Only when initiated.

Comment: I did the same with a step down transformer instead of SMPS and I saw this effect on the transformer secondary directly coupled to the scope by a coaxial cable.

Comment: On top of Marlas ground lead length, what's your scope-to-test-object groudning situation?

Comment: @winny I dont understand what you mean. But it is not about measurement probe or scope, SMPS is really get upset even if the scope is not there. I can see that because through that the rest of the unit gets upset such as a micro controller. The same type of spike ringing noise appears.

Comment: To draw conclusions from your oscilloscope measurements, you need to know the limitations of your setup first. Yes, you will still have a problem and you need to show layout and schematic to get help past that.

Comment: @winny Layout is basically from an AC power strip next to each other: the grinder, the SMPS supply and the scope(with an earthed prong) are powered. Then I connect the probe leads to the SMPS output terminals to observe the 5VDC output of the SMPS. And then start turn ON and OFF the grinder. Some of the turn ON times this phenomenon happens. I wish I had a handheld floating scope. Is there a quick way to verify 100% whether this is or not measurement related?

Comment: Seems normal, but a block diagram would help here. If your problem exists even without scope, we still need schematic and layout to help you. Probably poor layour and insufficient decoupling.

Comment: Okay I will try to update with more in detail asap. But right now I dont have the access to the details.

Comment: Any progress on the block diagram?

Answer (score 1):

SMPS as a unit has high bandwidth therefore any not filtered high frequency signal at its input will appear at its output. DC-DC linear chips are also have the same frequency response and any high frequency signal at their input could be appeared at their output.
just in case that you are using isolated transformer with iron core for an AC-DC convertor you have an intrinsically filter for some high frequency signals.

If you cascade proper Common Mode Filter at the DC/AC input and then proper low pass differential mode filter at the SMPS input, you could be sure about bypassing the injected noise at the input of SMPS from its output.
Remember for measurement such phenomena it is recommended to use probes in their X10 mode and do not use their attached long 3-4 inch Ground cable. you have to use the very short ground clips that is companion with probe's purchased package.

Ringing is also companion with an SMPS that is not implemented with good PCB. Please look at the related TI document (SLPA005).
In addition to conducted emission the Grinder has strong radiated emission too.
using proper casing and filter (Common mode) at the input and output of the SMPS could be helpful.
Please look at the following links:
https://www.giee.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ferrite_bead_181_hex_open_and_closed.jpg

https://www.radiodan.com/Henry/parts/RF_chokes.htm